# how to convert string to numerical values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to convert a string that contains a numerical value to its value in an aggregate query in MongoDB.

Example of document

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5522XXXXXXXXXXXX"),
   "Date": "2015-04-05",
   "PartnerID": "123456",
   "moop": "1234" 
}
```

Example of the aggregate query I use

```
{
    aggregate: 'my_collection',
    pipeline: [
         {$match: {
             Date : 
                  {$gt:'2015-04-01', 
                  $lt: '2015-04-05'
                  }}
             },
         {$group:
             {_id: "$PartnerID",
              total:{$sum:'$moop'}
             }}]}
```

where the results are

```
{
   "result": [
     {
       "_id": "123456",
       "total": NumberInt(0) 
    }
}
```

How can you convert the string to its numerical value?

Comment: With Mongo 4.0, there is an operator `$toInt` , cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488118/295716

Answer (score 39):

MongoDB aggregation not allowed to change existing data type of given fields. In this case you should create some programming code to convert `string` to `int`. Check below code

```js
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(data) {
    db.collectionName.update({
        "_id": data._id,
        "moop": data.moop
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "PartnerID": parseInt(data.PartnerID)
        }
    });
})
```

If your collections size more then above script will slow down the performance, for perfomace mongo provide [mongo bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) operations, using mongo bulk operations also updated data type

```js
var bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(data) {
    var updoc = {
        "$set": {}
    };
    var myKey = "PartnerID";
    updoc["$set"][myKey] = parseInt(data.PartnerID);
    // queue the update
    bulk.find({
        "_id": data._id
    }).update(updoc);
    counter++;
    // Drain and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
    })
    // Add the rest in the queue
if (counter % 1000 != 0) bulk.execute();
```

This basically reduces the amount of operations statements sent to the sever to only sending once every 1000 queued operations.

Comment: Thanks, used another method as stated below.

Comment: late to the party, but `bulk.execute()`, if called without parameters, returns a `Promise`. Your example didn't work for me until I began to treat it like a `Promise`. In my case with `co` I simply added `yield` in front of it.

Comment: Could you pls help on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165765/mongodb-how-to-parse-date-in-3-6-mongodb-version

Answer (score 31):

**Using MongoDB 4.0 and newer**

You have two options i.e. **[`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)** or **[`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert)**. Using **[`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)**, follow the example below:

```
filterDateStage = {
    '$match': {
        'Date': {
            '$gt': '2015-04-01', 
            '$lt': '2015-04-05'
        }
    }
};

groupStage = {
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$PartnerID',
        'total': { '$sum': { '$toInt': '$moop' } }
    }
};

db.getCollection('my_collection').aggregate([
   filterDateStage,
   groupStage
])
```

If the conversion operation encounters an error, the aggregation operation stops and throws an error. To override this behavior, use **[`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert)** instead.

Using **[`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert)**

```
groupStage = {
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$PartnerID',
        'total': { 
            '$sum': { 
                '$convert': { 'input': '$moop', 'to': 'int' }
            } 
        }
    }
};
```

---

**Using Map/Reduce**

With map/reduce you can use javascript functions like `parseInt()` to do the conversion. As an example, you could define the map function to process each input document:
In the function, `this` refers to the document that the map-reduce operation is processing. The function maps the converted `moop` string value to the `PartnerID` for each document and emits the `PartnerID` and converted `moop` pair. This is where the javascript native function `parseInt()` can be applied:

```
var mapper = function () {
    var x = parseInt(this.moop);
    emit(this.PartnerID, x);
};
```

Next, define the corresponding reduce function with two arguments `keyCustId` and `valuesMoop`. `valuesMoop` is an array whose elements are the integer `moop` values emitted by the map function and grouped by `keyPartnerID`.
The function reduces the `valuesMoop` array to the sum of its elements.

```
var reducer = function(keyPartnerID, valuesMoop) {
                  return Array.sum(valuesMoop);
              };

db.collection.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    reducer,
    {
        out : "example_results",
        query: { 
            Date: {
                $gt: "2015-04-01", 
                $lt: "2015-04-05"
            }
        }       
    }
 );

 db.example_results.find(function (err, docs) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(docs));
 });
```

For example, with the following sample collection of documents:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550c00f81bcc15211016699b"),
    "Date" : "2015-04-04",
    "PartnerID" : "123456",
    "moop" : "1234"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550c00f81bcc15211016699c"),
    "Date" : "2015-04-03",
    "PartnerID" : "123456",
    "moop" : "24"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550c00f81bcc15211016699d"),
    "Date" : "2015-04-02",
    "PartnerID" : "123457",
    "moop" : "21"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550c00f81bcc15211016699e"),
    "Date" : "2015-04-02",
    "PartnerID" : "123457",
    "moop" : "8"
}
```

The above Map/Reduce operation will save the results to the `example_results` collection and the shell command `db.example_results.find()` will give:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : "123456",
    "value" : 1258
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "123457",
    "value" : 29
}
```

Answer (score 29):

You can easily convert the string data type to numerical data type.

Don't forget to change collectionName & FieldName.
for ex : CollectionNmae : Users & FieldName : Contactno.

Try this query..

```
db.collectionName.find().forEach( function (x) {
x.FieldName = parseInt(x.FieldName);
db.collectionName.save(x);
});
```

Answer (score 21):

Eventually I used

```
db.my_collection.find({moop: {$exists: true}}).forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.moop = new NumberInt(obj.moop);
    db.my_collection.save(obj);
});
```

to turn `moop` from string to integer in my_collection following the example in Simone's answer [MongoDB: How to change the type of a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field).

Comment: Interating over an array takes much time.

Answer (score 15):

String can be converted to numbers in MongoDB v4.0 using [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) operator. In this case

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            moopNumber: { $toInt: "$moop" }
        }
    }
])
```

outputs:

```
{ "moopNumber" : 1234 }
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a pure MongoDB based solution for this problem which I just wrote for fun. It's effectively a server-side string-to-number parser which supports positive and negative numbers as well as decimals:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "moop": {
            $reduce: {
                "input": {
                    $map: { // split string into char array so we can loop over individual characters
                        "input": {
                            $range: [ 0, { $strLenCP: "$moop" } ] // using an array of all numbers from 0 to the length of the string
                        },
                        "in":{
                            $substrCP: [ "$moop", "$$this", 1 ] // return the nth character as the mapped value for the current index
                        }
                    }
                },
                "initialValue": { // initialize the parser with a 0 value
                    "n": 0, // the current number
                    "sign": 1, // used for positive/negative numbers
                    "div": null, // used for shifting on the right side of the decimal separator "."
                    "mult": 10 // used for shifting on the left side of the decimal separator "."
                }, // start with a zero
                "in": {
                    $let: {
                        "vars": {
                            "n": {
                                $switch: { // char-to-number mapping
                                    branches: [
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "1" ] }, "then": 1 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "2" ] }, "then": 2 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "3" ] }, "then": 3 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "4" ] }, "then": 4 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "5" ] }, "then": 5 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "6" ] }, "then": 6 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "7" ] }, "then": 7 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "8" ] }, "then": 8 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "9" ] }, "then": 9 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "0" ] }, "then": 0 },
                                        { "case": { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$this", "-" ] }, { $eq: [ "$$value.n", 0 ] } ] }, "then": "-" }, // we allow a minus sign at the start
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "." ] }, "then": "." }
                                    ],
                                    default: null // marker to skip the current character
                                } 
                            }
                        },
                        "in": {
                            $switch: {
                                "branches": [
                                    {
                                        "case": { $eq: [ "$$n", "-" ] },
                                        "then": { // handle negative numbers
                                            "sign": -1, // set sign to -1, the rest stays untouched
                                            "n": "$$value.n",
                                            "div": "$$value.div",
                                            "mult": "$$value.mult",
                                        },
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "case": { $eq: [ "$$n", null ] }, // null is the "ignore this character" marker
                                        "then": "$$value" // no change to current value
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "case": { $eq: [ "$$n", "." ] },
                                        "then": { // handle decimals
                                            "n": "$$value.n",
                                            "sign": "$$value.sign",
                                            "div": 10, // from the decimal separator "." onwards, we start dividing new numbers by some divisor which starts at 10 initially
                                            "mult": 1, // and we stop multiplying the current value by ten
                                        },
                                    }, 
                                ],
                                "default": {
                                    "n": {
                                        $add: [
                                            { $multiply: [ "$$value.n", "$$value.mult" ] }, // multiply the already parsed number by 10 because we're moving one step to the right or by one once we're hitting the decimals section
                                            { $divide: [ "$$n", { $ifNull: [ "$$value.div", 1 ] } ] } // add the respective numerical value of what we look at currently, potentially divided by a divisor
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "sign": "$$value.sign",
                                    "div": { $multiply: [ "$$value.div" , 10 ] },
                                    "mult": "$$value.mult"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: { // fix sign
        "moop": { $multiply: [ "$moop.n", "$moop.sign" ] }
    }
})
```

I am certainly not advertising this as the bee's knees or anything and it might have severe performance implications for larger datasets over a client based solutions but there might be cases where it comes in handy...

The above pipeline will transform the following documents:

```
{ "moop": "12345" } --> { "moop": 12345 }
```

and

```
{ "moop": "123.45" } --> { "moop": 123.45 }
```

and

```
{ "moop": "-123.45" } --> { "moop": -123.45 }
```

and

```
{ "moop": "2018-01-03" } --> { "moop": 20180103.0 }
```

Comment: Is this the only mongo approach for version lower than 4.0

Comment: It's certainly the only one I ever wrote/could think of. And, honestly, upgrading is a better option.

Comment: This is a great exercise at least - well done!

Answer (score 7):

Three things need to care for:

1. parseInt() will store double data type in mongodb. Please use new NumberInt(string).
2. in Mongo shell command for bulk usage, yield won't work. Please DO NOT add 'yield'.
3. If you already change string to double by parseInt(). It looks like you have no way to change the type to int directly. The solution is a little bit wired: change double to string first and then change back to int by new NumberInt().

Comment: No, ParseInt never store as double, rather int32.

Answer (score 3):

If you can edit all documents in aggregate :

```
"TimeStamp": {$toDecimal: {$toDate: "$Your Date"}}
```

And for the client, you set the query :

```
Date.parse("Your date".toISOString())
```

That's what makes you whole work with ISODate.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
"TimeStamp":{$toDecimal: { $toDate:"$Datum"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though `$toInt` is really useful, it was added on mongoDB 4.0, I've run into this same situation in a database running 3.2 which upgrading to use `$toInt` was not an option due to some other application incompatibilities, so i had to come up with something else, and actually was surprisingly simple.

If you `$project` and `$add` zero to your string, it will turn into a number

```
{
  $project : {
  'convertedField' : { $add : ["$stringField",0] },
  //more fields here...
  }
}
```

Comment: mongodb ver 3.6.18 , "message" : "$add only supports numeric or date types, not string",

Comment: @gvasquez I think you've missed the part where it says I was running 3.2, not 3.6. Something has probably changed in the mean time.

Answer (score 1):

It should be saved. It should be like this :

```
     db. my_collection.find({}).forEach(function(theCollection) {
         theCollection.moop = parseInt(theCollection.moop);
        db.my_collection.save(theCollection);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Collation is what you need:

```
db.collectionName.find().sort({PartnerID: 1}).collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})
```

Answer (score -2):

> db.user.find().toArray().filter(a=>a.age>40)