# Why does the following mongodb group query return always 0?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following sample json, it doesn't seem to be too hard.
Basically I'm trying to group all objects by the algorithm field, and then calculate the average from the $difference.close field.

The following is a sample object

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b0c702c783c42f504f006c"),
    "symbol" : "ALSK",
    "algorithm" : "AvgForecaster",
    "date" : "2016-02-01",
    "real_quote" : {
        "trade_date" : "2016-02-01",
        "open" : "1.6",
        "close" : "1.59",
        "low" : "1.57",
        "high" : "1.66",
        "volume" : "65600",
        "symbol" : "ALSK",
        "adjusted_close" : "1.59"
    },
    "forecasted_quote" : {
        "trade_date" : "2016-02-01",
        "open" : "0.0",
        "close" : "1.92",
        "low" : "0.0",
        "high" : "0.0",
        "volume" : "0",
        "symbol" : "ALSK",
        "adjusted_close" : "0.0"
    },
    "difference" : {
        "trade_date" : "2016-02-01",
        "open" : "1.6",
        "close" : "-0.33",
        "low" : "1.57",
        "high" : "1.66",
        "volume" : "65600",
        "symbol" : "ALSK",
        "adjusted_close" : "1.59"
    }
}
```

Then the query is as follows:

```
db.getCollection('Accuchecks').aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$algorithm",
        accuracy: {$avg: "$difference.close"}
     }
}])
```

And then I get the following result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "DeltaForecaster",
            "accuracy" : 0.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "AvgForecaster",
            "accuracy" : 0.0000000000000000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Could the query is not picking the $difference.close field? In the full collection that value almost never 0.

Thanks

Comment: No, it's picking the `$difference.close` field fine but because it holds string values, the `$avg` operator will not work, only does so on numerical fields. So change your schema so that the `$difference.close` field holds numerical values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting back a 0, as you are storing your `close` values as strings instead of floats. There are no type-conversions functions available in the  aggregation pipeline, so you will have to store your values as numerical values instead, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487351/how-to-convert-string-to-numerical-values-in-mongodb) on how to change the type of your existing data.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b0c702c783c42f504f006c"),
    "symbol" : "ALSK",
    "algorithm" : "AvgForecaster",
    "date" : "2016-02-01",
    "real_quote" : {
        "trade_date" : "2016-02-01",
        "open" : 1.6,
        "close" : 1.59,
        "low" : 1.57,
        "high" : 1.66,
        "volume" : 65600,
        "symbol" : "ALSK",
        "adjusted_close" : 1.59
    },
    "forecasted_quote" : {
        "trade_date" : "2016-02-01",
        "open" : 0.0,
        "close" : 1.92,
        "low" : 0.0,
        "high" : 0.0,
        "volume" : 0,
        "symbol" : "ALSK",
        "adjusted_close" : 0.0
    },
    "difference" : {
        "trade_date" : "2016-02-01",
        "open" : 1.6,
        "close" : -0.33,
        "low" : 1.57,
        "high" : 1.66,
        "volume" : "65600",
        "symbol" : "ALSK",
        "adjusted_close" : .59
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much... that was easy: db.getCollection('Accuchecks').find({}).forEach( function(obj) { obj.difference.close = parseFloat( obj.difference.close ); 
db.getCollection('Accuchecks').save(obj); } );