# MongoDB - Perform $divide on String fields

Tags: mongodb, casting, aggregation-framework

I am trying to perform an aggregation query on a collection. I want to divide 2 of the fields and check if this is less than a certain value.

The way this db was made, it has all the fields as strings, and this isn't something I can really change right now. I wondered if there was a way to cast the values as numbers, maybe using $let or something?

As it is I currently get the error

```
exception: $divide only supports numeric types, not String and String
```

This is an example of the sort of query I am trying to run:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "mins": {
            "$divide": ["$ALOWOVRLTOTL", "$FEESCALLCOST"]}
         }
     },
     "$match": {
         "mins": {
              "$lte": 40
          }
      }
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay attention to the exception. And adjust your query accordingly.

> exception: $divide only supports numeric types, not String and String

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
"$project": {
    "mins": {
        "$divide": [{'$toDouble': '$ALOWOVRLTOTL' }, {'$toDouble': '$FEESCALLCOST' }]}
     }
 },
 "$match": {
     "mins": {
          "$lte": 40
      }
  }
}])
```

You have several types available to convert your string values to depending on your particular situation. Find below a list of types you can convert.

- $toDecimal
- $toDouble
- $toInt
- $toLong

See MongoDB official [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) on Conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to perform the `divide` operation on non-numerical values. A possible solution to this would be to run an update and parse the `String` values to a numerical value.

Have a look at this question:
[how to convert string to numerical values in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487351/how-to-convert-string-to-numerical-values-in-mongodb)