# MongoDB type update from NumberLong to String

Tags: mysql, mongodb, csv, mongo-shell

I've imported CSV file to my mongodb. CSV have separators as needed to mongo and was received from MySQL database with this query:
`SELECT * FROM csgo_users INTO OUTFILE 'b1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';` 
Also I've tried to receive CSV from Sequel Pro with it's export functions.

In my csv I have field with 17 characters length. In MySQL database this field has type VARCHAR but contains 17-digits number.
After importing csv to mongo I got this field with type `NumberLong`, but I want it to be `string`.
I've tried so far to:

- Change type in MySQL from `varchar` to `text`.
- Tried to import csv with additional flags `--headerline` and `--columnsHaveTypes`
- Also I've tried to add separate fields without top line, with tag `--fields`.
- Tried commands as this:

  ```
  db.csgo_users.find({"steam_id": {$type: 18}})
         .toArray()
         .map(function(v){
             v.steam_id = new String(v); 
             db.csgo_users.save(v)
          })
  ```

or this:

```
db.csgo_users.find({"steam_id": {$type: 18}})
  .toArray()
  .map(function(v){
     v.steam_id = new String(v.toSring());
     db.csgo_users.save(v)
  })
```

- I've tried a lot of solutions with `forEach()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29487693/6066986) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4973632/6066986) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7796204/6066986)
 etc.

For the last one example of my tries I've got not string, but Object, `{"N",u","m","b","e","r","L","o","n","g"..}` but I want it to be "123456789", not Object. 
I'm using MongoDB 3.4 [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/).
**So, my question is, how to change "field" type from `NumberLong` to `String`?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use valueOf() to get the value of a NumberLong as a javascript number value.

**Casting NumberLong to Number :**

```
NumberLong('5').valueOf() // 5
```

Then, you can then use easilly `toString()` on your number to get the String value.

**Casting NumberLong to String :**

```
NumberLong('5').valueOf().toString() // "5"
```

Comment: Can you please show me example of mongo shell query where I can use `.valueOf()`? Because I want to select all fields where my field with `$type: 18` which is `NumberLong`, and then replace with the same value but `.toString()`.

Comment: I've got this, just changed my code with .valueOf(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it is a long number, it regreses to a number that isn't accurate

Answer (score 6):

The type `NumberLong` exists for a reason, to handle huge numbers, similar to `BigInt` on SQL. MongoDB relies on JavaScript which have at most 53 bits for integers, in ES6 the largest exact integral value is 2<sup>53</sup>-1, or 9007199254740991, for this reason, "converting" from NumberLong to a simple string isn't as simple as the previous answer, here is an example:

```js
var huge = NumberLong("987654321987654321");
huge.valueOf(); // 987654321987654300
huge.toString(); // NumberLong("987654321987654321")
huge.valueOf().toString(); // 987654321987654300
```

With this example, it is clear that JavaScript is rounding up the numbers while using `valueOf()`, and lacking any sane response and documentation, I came with a workaround for this situation, using RegEx to remove any non numerical characters from the `toString()` function:

```js
huge.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, '') // 987654321987654321
```

It isn't pretty, but it works, any other better solution is always appreciated. As a bonus fact, using `JSON.stringify` converts the value into an object using the special char `$` to represent the function to call while processing the value, the way MongoDB handles this issues while dealing with common day to day JSON objects:

```js
JSON.stringify(huge) // {"$numberLong":"987654321987654321"}
```

**Update:**
The right way of converting data with MongoDB is with aggregations using a projection:

```js
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
    {$match: {
        /* your match query object */
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: 0, // to ignore the document id
        myStringObj: {$toString: '$myNumberLongObj'} // from NumberLong to String
    }},
], {allowDiskUse: true});
```

Comment: In regexps, `\D` is the opposite of `\d`, so it can be written slightly shorter: `huge.toString().replace(/\D/g,"")`