# Mongo Cast String to Number for Query

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to do a less than or equal to query on a string field of a number?

Example Data

```
|           Id           |           Price           |
|           1            |           "1000.00"       |
|           2            |           "5400.00"       |
|           3            |           "750.00"        |
```

When I execute this query it returns all of the records:

```
db.MyCollection.find({ Price: {$lte: "1000.0"} })
```

When I execute this query it returns nothing:

```
db.MyCollection.find({ Price: {$lte: 1000.0} })
```

Answer (score 13):

**Update (valid from MongoDB v4.0 onwards):**

You can use a combination of [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) and [$toDouble](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/index.html) to achieve the desired behaviour like this:

```
db.MyCollection.find({ $expr: { $lte: [ { $toDouble: "$Price" }, 1000.0 ] } })
```

**Original Answer (MongoDB v3.6 and below):**

MongoDB cannot convert strings to numbers. So your only option here is to use the dreaded [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator:

```
db.MyCollection.find({ $where: "parseInt(this.Price) <= 1000" })
```

This won't use any indexes and is not exactly fast but perhaps kind of ok still for small collections.

Nonetheless I would recommend storing numbers as numerical types. So you should convert your `string`s to `int`s or `long`s (or probably `double`s even) as shown here: [how to convert string to numerical values in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487351/how-to-convert-string-to-numerical-values-in-mongodb)

Comment: I find this frustrating. Isn't the point of using MongoDB that you can have a flexible schema (one day you're storing strings, the next day numbers, and they all work). Now, it seems, I need to go back and convert all these string number values into numbers.

Comment: @Joao, cannot agree more with you.

Comment: @Joao if you have a property with a numerical value in some objects and a string value in others, how do you decide what's greater and what's less?  Do you compare the numbers as if they were strings?  If not, do you compare the numerical strings as if they were numbers?  What do you do with the strings that can't be converted to numbers?  The answers to these questions will be different for different applications, so it doesn't make sense for the database to support it directly; most people will find that the implementation doesn't fit their needs anyway.