# Convert a string to a number in Shell Mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, shell, find

I have a Mongodb Collection in which a decimal amount is stored as a string.
I would like to be able to query treating that field as a number.
Is that possible without elaborate code? I would expect to be able to do. tonumber(field):{$gt:100}.
But I can't find anything.

Comment: Actually I have that wrong. tonumber(field):{$gt:100}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915936/mongo-cast-string-to-number-for-query/47919019