# How to display records in descending order in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a table in MongoDB in which I can get the fields in descending order
sorted by system_id

```
db.job_parameters_mongo.find().sort({system_id : -1})
```

This is fine but gives me incorrect result as system_id is string field.Is there any way that I can convert system_id to number before ordering in descending order.I saw on this site that there is a way to do this using forEach ([how to convert string to numerical values in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487351/how-to-convert-string-to-numerical-values-in-mongodb)) but that uses a function.Isn't there any other way like we have to_number in rdbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) available in 4.0 version.

```
db.job_parameters_mongo.aggregate([
 {"$addFields":{"system_id":{"$toInt":"$system_id"}}}, 
 {"$sort":{"system_id":-1}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.I tried  executing db.job_parameters_mongo.aggregate([{"$addFields":{"system_id":{"$toInt:"$system_id"}}},{"$sort":{"system_id":-1}}]) but getting error 
2018-09-05T20:44:59.111+0530 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:72 .Is there any colon missing

Comment: yw. yeah missing closing quotes after $toInt. Try `[{"$addFields":{"system_id":{"$toInt":"$system_id"}}},{"$sort":{"system_id":-1}}]`. Updated answer as well.