# How Can I increment some number field (but String) with a specific condition in Mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi Everyone of StackOverflow Community,

I have a doubt in an activity that I have to do for homework.

I want to know how I can increment one field in every document that is filtered by a specific condition. My problem is not in the update code, in termes that this number field to increment was a number type (int, float, double,...), but yes when I have to increment that field values (numbers)  in a field that has String as a field type.

It give my that error (ScreenShot):

[ERROR MongoDB Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmY8N.png)

Thanks.

See you,

Comment: As you've found, you can't use `$inc` with string values. Can you update your question with a specific example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: JohnnyHK, what I'm trying to do with $Inc is to sum 5 to a a field that has String as type

Comment: You can't do that in a single update; you'd have to find the document, convert the string to number, add 5, convert it back to a string, and update the document with `$set`.

Comment: Ok. I understood more or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it is like [JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk) said in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691936/how-can-i-increment-some-number-field-but-string-with-a-specific-condition-in/55768968#comment98079756_55691936):

> You can't do that in a single update; you'd have to find the document, convert the string to number, add 5, convert it back to a string, and update the document with `$set`.

Another possibility is found in the following question:

- [how to convert string to numerical values in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487351/how-to-convert-string-to-numerical-values-in-mongodb)

Comment: Ok Wai Ha Lee (I know to put the link as a unorganized list with 1item) and I also know ho to make a cite to a comment (I didn't do because I thought it was intuitive) , but how did you put the mention to JohnnyHK? (typing its user profile URL?)

Comment: Thanks. [Wai Ha Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364007/wai-ha-lee) !!