# How to convert string to int in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

How do i change data of type String to Int in MongoDB. ( Preferably in MongoCompass or Terminal )

I have received a pretty huge dataset with the documents in the following format

[image]

To add it to my existing data i need to change the ean from type string to type int.
I already tried the following:

```
db.products.aggregate([{$project: {ean: { $toInt: "$ean"}}}])
```

Which gave me the error:

```
MongoError: Failed to parse number '0002983542515' in $convert with no onError value: Overflow
```

So i tried the same with convert:

```
db.products.aggregate([{$project: {_id: 0, result:{ $convert: { input: "ean", to: "int", onError: "An error occured", onNull: "input was null or empty"}}}}])
```

This is the console.log i got from that:

```
[ { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' },
  { result: 'An error occured' } ]
```

My ean field didn't change, its still from type String.

Any help is highly appreciated

Trying Rakhi Agrawal solution:

[image]

but its still a string:

[image]

Comment: try `$toLong` operator.. because integer exceeded the limit.

Comment: Good point unfortunately that did not solve the issue

Comment: db.products.aggregate([{$project: {ean: { $toLong: "$ean"}}}])

[ { _id: ObjectId("60522fe2eec53799e3faa6bf"), ean: null },
  { _id: ObjectId("605a77cb5177059bebf0ad0a"), ean: null }, ... ]

Comment: what are you getting in result? see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dTan13ucrjC)

Comment: It is working in the playground but not on the MongoDB compass. 
Maybe because the field was created as string?

Comment: no, make sure any of the document in `ean` field should not contain any alphabets / special characters.

Comment: what are you actually want to do? do you want to update that field from string to number in database permanently? it just want temporary formatted result?

Comment: I have to collections right now. One with my production data and one with this new data, now i want to add the new data to my production data but the data types have to be the same. The only data type that is different is the ean.

Comment: okay where you are executing this converter `$toLong` query?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487351/how-to-convert-string-to-numerical-values-in-mongodb)?

You may also find many examples over internet for the same. Below is the snippet from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb-query-to-convert-string-to-int)

> ```
>  db.demo369.insertOne({"Price":"1000000"});
>  db.demo369.find().forEach( function (d) {
>      d.Price= parseInt(d.Price);
>      db.demo369.save(d);
>  });
> ```

Hope I got the question right.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i tried that and it did not change the type of the field it is still string