# How to add two strings as numbers together in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

my guestMin and guestMax are both strings, and I want to add them together and put the sum into guestSum.

I tried this:

```
$project:{
    "_id" : 1,                                 
    "name" : 1,
    "guestsMin" : 1,
    "guestsMax" : 1,
    "guestSum" : parseInt("guestsMin") + parseInt("guestsMax"),
    "gmapsdata" : 1
}
```

this does not show the guestSum at all

```
$project:{
    "_id" : 1,                                 
    "name" : 1,
    "guestsMin" : 1,
    "guestsMax" : 1,
    "guestSum" : { $add: [ parseInt("guestsMin"), parseInt("guestsMax") ] },
    "gmapsdata" : 1
}
```

this gives "guestSum": null,

```
    "guestSum" : { $add: [ parseInt("$guestsMin"), parseInt("$guestsMax") ] },
```

this gives "guestSum": null,

```
    "guestSum" : { $multiply: [ parseInt("$guestsMin"), parseInt("$guestsMax") ] },
```

this gives "guestSum": null,

```
    "guestSum" : { $multiply: [ parseInt("property.guestsMin"), parseInt("property.guestsMax") ] },
```

this gives "guestSum": null,

Im running out of ideas, anyone?

Comment: seems like you cannot convert the string to the number in aggregation pipeline https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983228/convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-mongodb-projection

Comment: @Sergey hmmm perhaps you are right - but when I remove the parseInt, then it complains about multiplying strings.  So it looks like the parseInt part is working fine.  Just crap that I have to do a loop in js to add these two numbers together.

Comment: The right thing to do here is fix all the docs so that these fields use numeric values. Otherwise you'll be fighting this forever.

Comment: @JohnnyHK hehe exactly!!   So I did - last night I converted all the guestMin and guestMax to be numeric.  And that made things a lot more easy

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this:

```
"guestSort" : { $multiply: [ "$guestsMin", "$guestsMax"] },
```

`"property.guestsMin"` did not work

`"guestsMin"` did not work

`"$property.guestsMin"` did not work

but... `"$guestsMin"` worked